# Как добавить пункты в spinner из EditText по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, gettext

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner MainSpinner;
    private Button Button;
    String[] spinner1;
    int i=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        EditText EditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        // адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner1);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner MainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MainSpinner);
        MainSpinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }

    public void onClick(View Button) {
        spinner1[i]=(EditText.getText());
        i=i+1;
    }

}
```

Нужно добавить пункт в `spinner` из `EditText` при нажатии на кнопку. У меня ругается на слово `getText`. Выдаёт:

> non-static method 'getText()' cannot be referenced from a static context

В чём проблема? Можно ли вообще добавлять пункты (`items`) в `spinner` по нажатию на кнопку? Как это реализовать правильно?

Comment: Пишет что метод не статический. Такое бывает если вызвать метод  без инициализации объекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример для Вас.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> spinner1 = new ArrayList<>();
EditText editText;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Spinner mainSpinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner1.add("IM YOU FIRST SPINNER NAME!");
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    mainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MainSpinner);

    // адаптер
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mainSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    spinner1.add(editText.getText().toString());
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mainSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Всё работает! Только один нюанс: Вы забыли инициализировать кнопку (Button). Я её сам инициализировал и всё прекрасно работает! Ещё раз спасибо! Удачи Вам!

Comment: Вы можете навязать метод (onClick) в xml файле для Вашей кнопке, тогда инициализацию нет необходимости делать в классе. Пожалуйста, обращайтесь.

Comment: Здравствуйте ещё раз! Сегодня хотел добавить if в программу для проверки значения EditText, а он в упор отказывается работать. Хоть условие выполняется, хоть нет - результата ноль. Как будто этого if и нету в программе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно добавить условный оператор, чтобы он работал. Вот код:          'public void onClick(View button) {
        if ((editText.getText().toString()) == "12345") {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Проверка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();'

Comment: Всё, уже не надо! Ввёл новую переменную CurrentText присвоил ей значение из EditText и написал так: 'if (CurrentText.equals("12345")) ', и теперь всё работает! Всё равно спасибо за помощь! Без Вас я бы не написал эту программу! До свидания!

Answer (score 4):

Имена переменных принято писать с маленькой буквы. И не зря. Именно из-за этого у вас проблема. Вы назвали переменную типа `EditText` именем `EditText` и компилятор теперь не знает что вы пытаетесь ему приказать: вызвать статический (и не существующий) метод у класса `EditText` или вызвать его у вашей переменной. А т.к. он ожидает, что вы код правильно пишете он таки интерпретирует ваш приказ как вызов несуществующего статического метода класса `EditText`, о чём вам и сообщает.

---

Также у вас массив для пунктов спиннера не инициализирован и программа упадёт из-за этого на этапе попытки в него что-то добавить. Думаю, вам надо не массив использовать а список (`ArrayList` например). и не забыть его инициализировать. И адаптер спинера уведомлять об изменениях в нём.

Comment: да даже если всё это сделать там ещё будет куча ошибок

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, наверняка. Но надо же с чего-то начать) А как такое со спинером сделать я сходу и не соображу)

Comment: Ну да))) там Edit не попадает даже в видимость, button не иниц, потом листнер повешен, но выводится вне класса, потом с адаптером ошибки бы были и да EditText - Editable а нужен String

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, ага, всё печально)